# Rounded button on Outlook.com/Outlook 2013 using TD

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I'm designing an email, and I want to have a button with rounded corners on Outlook.com and Outlook 2013. I use `td` and the following CSS:

`<td style="background-color: rgb(0, 112, 210); margin: 0px auto; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; padding: 12px 16px; border: none; border-top-left-radius: 4px; border-top-right-radius: 4px; border-bottom-right-radius: 4px; border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;"><a target="_blank" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration: none; text-align: center; text-transform: none; font-size: 16px;">BUtton!</a></td>`

(P.S. It works fine on almost all email clients including Outlook 2016, 2011, gmail, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to get CSS rounded corners with Outlook 2013, 2016. It doesn't currently work in Outlook 2016.

You could have Outlook set up to load a rounded graphic in the background using vml.